# Displaying Triangle in JavaFX using Inner Class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create an Inner Class to create a Triangle based on given variables and then display it in a JavaFX Scene. My Current code is shown below:

```
public class OuterClass extends Application {
public class InnerClass extends Polygon {
    Polygon triangle;
    InnerClass(double x, double y, double side) {
        double mySideSqrt = Math.sqrt((side * side) - (side / 2 * side / 2)) / 2;
        double tX = x;
        double tY = y - mySideSqrt;
        double rX = x + side / 2;
        double rY = y + mySideSqrt;
        double lX = x - side / 2;
        double lY = y + mySideSqrt;

        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(tX, tY, rX, rY, lX, lY);
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    int myWidth = 600;
    int myHeight = 519;

    primaryStage.setTitle("Triangle");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, myWidth, myHeight);

    //Polygon triangle = new Polygon(100.0, 0.0, 200.0, 173.3, 0, 173.3); //100.0, 0.0, 200.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0
    InnerClass triangle = new InnerClass(300, 260, 196);
    triangle.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    root.getChildren().add(triangle);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

When I debug the code, it seems to be breaking at the line:

```
InnerClass triangle = new InnerClass(300, 260, 196);
```

Because the triangle created in the inner class isnt pulled into method, and therefore not displayed in the scene.

Any ideas on how Ican get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Polygon triangle;` and change `Polygon triangle = new Polygon(tX, tY, rX, rY, lX, lY); this.triangle = triangle;` to `getPoints().addAll(tX, tY, rX, rY, lX, lY);`

Full class:

```
public class InnerClass extends Polygon {
    InnerClass(double x, double y, double side) {
        double mySideSqrt = Math.sqrt((side * side) - (side / 2 * side / 2)) / 2;
        double tX = x;
        double tY = y - mySideSqrt;
        double rX = x + side / 2;
        double rY = y + mySideSqrt;
        double lX = x - side / 2;
        double lY = y + mySideSqrt;

        getPoints().addAll(tX, tY, rX, rY, lX, lY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, works well. Can you explain a bit why exactly "getPoints().addAll(tX, tY, rX, rY, lX, lY);" works over my method? im assuming its passing in those variables into the Polygon function?

Comment: You created two Polygon's the first one was the `InnerClass` who doesn't hold any points and the second one with the points was hidden inside of the first.